# Explanation of an integral

Tags: integration

I want to find the distribution function of this integral but i do not understand how to solve it, although i know the result.

$$F_X(t)=\int_{0}^t \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$$

Comment: Hint: $\int g'(x)f'(g(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x =  f(g(x))$

Comment: An antiderivative is easy to spot. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  Is $\lambda$ a function or a constant?  If it's a constant... well, what's the $\int e^{cx}dx$?